# organize post data to insert into differnt row of one table

Tags: php, mysql

I am posting complex form and have such post data

```
 [School_Name] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => l
        [2] => o
    )

[feild_Name] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => l
        [2] => o
    )
```

I want to insert such data in one table but with different row means `_1` will insert by one row  and `_2` will insert by second row both having one common  column id

problem Is how can I get data separately to set in one row

my strops() function is not working

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
$return = strpos('_edu_',$key);
echo $return;
}
```

Comment: Name you html inputs like `School_Name_edu[]` and `Degree_Name_edu[]` instead of `Degree_Name_edu_1` then loop through the post array `$_POST['Degree_Name_edu']` and `$_POST['School_Name_edu']`.

Comment: actuly sir my form is complex I am appending one hidden form multiple times to differentiate it  using js to append name attribute by counter every times

Comment: @bassxzero sir I have edit my question now I am getting such post data how can now organize data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding your having the following form

```
name="School_Name[counter]" //Counter is the one added by javascript on the fly
```

The problem is when you do the above way all School_Name values will be stored in the single key.

As you said that your using javascript for counter. Why don't you do the following way

By default it will have counter as 1 as follows

```
<div>
    <input name="Details[1][School_Name]">
    <input name="Details[1][College_Name]">
</div>
```

On click of any button or performing any loop you can increment the counter by one which now looks like the following

```
<div>
    <input name="Details[2][School_Name]">
    <input name="Details[2][College_Name]">
</div>
```

Once you follow the above way you will now get the array as follows

```
[Details]
    [1] => 
        [School_Name] => 'XYZ',
        [College_Name] => 'UGJ'

    [2] => 
        [School_Name] => 'ABC',
        [College_Name] => 'NUV'
```

Now if you loop just the details array you will get per loop values easily to handle.